# mismatched input 'org' expecting StringLiteral near 'BY' in table file format specification

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-dynamodb, hiveql

I am trying to load a hive table from Dynamo table . However I ran into an error which I am not able to resolve . PFB the code

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE CL_AL (COL1 string, 
                              COL2 string, 
                               COL3 string ,
                              COL4 string , 
                              COL5 string, 
                              COL6 string , 
                              COL7 string , 
                              COL8 string , 
                              COL9 string, 
                              COL10 string , 
                              COL11 string, 
                              COL12 string)
STORED BY “org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler”
TBLPROPERTIES (“dynamodb.table.name” =  “CL_AL”, 
“dynamodb.column.mapping” = “COL1: COL1, COL2: COL2, COL3:COL3 , COL4:COL4, 
COL5: COL5, COL6: COL6,COL7: COL7 , COL8: COL8, COL9: COL9 , COL10:  COL10 , COL11: COL11 , COL12: COL12”);
```

When I run this code through terminal , I get the following error 
    "mismatched input 'org' expecting StringLiteral near 'BY' in table file   format specification".

As mentioned in other posts, I have tried replacing the quotes with '' and " " . However the issue still persists . there are no keywords as column names in my tables . Could someone please help me resolve this issue

Comment: did you try this ? STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler' , keeping in sigle quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue . The issue was with the TextEdit (Notepad of Mac) . In TextEdit , the single quotes (') is treated as (‘) . Hence the hive was not recognizing the single quotes . I copied the whole code into Atom and then copied the code from Atom to hive terminal . The code ran without any issues.